# ASP.NET MVC Two models in ove view, code change

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I had this code and it worked fine:

```
@model IEnumerable<Moviestore.Models.Movie>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
if (item.IsDeleted == 0)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MovieID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
}
</table>
```

But I needed to add one more model, I done that with Tuple In this way:

```
@using Moviestore.Models;
@model Tuple<Movie, User>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>           
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Title)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Genre)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Author)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Year)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
if (item.IsDeleted == 0)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MovieID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
}
</table>
```

But now I have problem with bottom half of code.
From @foreach

I don't know what I need to put instead of @foreach (var item in **Model**)

And will then @Html.DisplayFor(**modelItem** => **item.Title**) also need some changes.

Sorry for long post, I tried to explain the problem as best as I can.

Comment: The appropriate way to handle this situation (needing more than one model on a particular View page) is to use a ViewModel which contains the models you need.

Comment: Yes. If you want to use models m1 and m2 to use in your view then create another model (vm) which has got members for m1 and m2.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, the appropriate way to handle this situation (needing more than one model on a particular View page) is to use a ViewModel which contains the models you need (see [here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469192/mvc-viewmodel-example)).

To answer your specific question, though, you can access each item of the Tuple by its position, e.g. if your model is `Tuple<Movie, User>`, then you can access the Movie object by `model.Item1` and the User object by `model.Item2`, etc.

But I strongly recommend you take the ViewModel approach that I linked instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the viewmodel for your requirement:

```
public class MovieUserViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

With the above viewmodel  , you can easily access each class

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Movie)

@foreach (var item in Model.Users)
```

Additional info : [Understanding ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/understanding-viewmodel-in-aspnet-mvc)

Thanks

Karthik