# Getting model to viewmodel easily

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view-model like this:

```
public class U1MyProfile1ViewModel : U1Profile
{
    public List<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }
}
```

Thinking that I want the model accessible to the view, plus a some extra fields that aren't really part of the model, such as a drop down list of countries.

Then in the controller I try to "pass the model over to the view-model"

```
        var myProfile = await _mainDbContext.U1Profiles
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.SiteUserId == mySiteUserId);

        U1MyProfile1ViewModel myProfileViewModel = (U1MyProfile1ViewModel)myProfile;
```

this compiles, but I get a runtime error of:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WebApp.Models.U1Profile' to type 'WebApp.ViewModels.U1MyProfile1ViewModel'.

Any ideas on how to do this easily?
Something simpler than assigning the model to the view-model field by field.

Comment: If you do not want to initialize and map `U1Profile` to `U1MyProfile1ViewModel`, then you can consider using [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) - but you would still need to populate the SelectList

Comment: Why you inherits viewmodel to model? View model is always work freely without depending on anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your View model like follow:

**View modal**

```
public class U1MyProfile1ViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }
    public U1Profile U1Profile{get;set;}
    public string othervariable{get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
var myProfile = await _mainDbContext.U1Profiles
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.SiteUserId == mySiteUserId);

        U1MyProfile1ViewModel myProfileViewModel = new U1MyProfile1ViewModel;
       U1MyProfile1ViewModel.U1Profile=myProfile;
       U1MyProfile1ViewModel.CountryList=yourcountrylist;
```

And finally just passed your viewmodal to View and you get your result.

For better understanding just see below link:
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469192/mvc-viewmodel-example)
[Link2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/view-model-in-mvc-with-example)

Comment: View model should not contain data models when editing data - it defeats the whole point of using view model (separation of concerns, protection against over-posting attacks, protection against under-posting attacks etc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke make sense. Thanks. How we deal with this ?